# Google Analytics Shopping Behavior Analysis Missing Data

Tags: magento2, google-analytics, google-enhanced

i've created an ecommerce store and created the analytics for this store,
On Magento2 backend i've placed the Tracking Code and i start to check that the data is being sent into GA.
The enhanced eCommerce is already enabled and collecting order data.
The issue is the Shopping Analysis Behavior that is missing data on some steps

- Sessions with Product Views
- Sessions with Add to Cart
- Sessions with Checkout

I've attached a printscreen of this.

[image]

Regards

Comment: Do you find a solution for it?

Comment: Found any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this issue by using the Free Version of [this plugin](https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-tag-manager-magento-2.html)

This provide additional data to be tracked in GA such as addToCart, removeFromCart, etc
Hope this helps someone!